# Sweetalert delete confirm button is not working in laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

Hello guys I'M having an issue with my sweetalert delete confirmation. When I click on "Yes Delete it!" nothing happens and there are no errors showing in my console please guys I seriously need help this has kept me on deck for a long time now. I really be grateful if I get quick responses.

This is my blade.php

```
<button onclick="deleteConfirmation({{$poster->id}})" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-confirm offset-md-2">Delete</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function deleteConfirmation(id) {
       swal({
             title: "Delete?",
             text: "Are you sure you want to delete this?",
             type: "warning",
             showCancelButton: true,
             confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
             cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
             reverseButtons: true
         }).then(function (e) {

             if (e.value) {
                 var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'DELETE',
                     url: "{{ url('delete-post') }}" + '/' + id,
                     data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
                     dataType: 'JSON',
                     success: function (results) {

                         if (results.success === true) {
                             swal("Done!", results.message, "success");
                         } else {
                             swal("Error!", results.message, "error");
                         }
                     }
                 });

             } else {
                 e.dismiss;
             }

         }, function (dismiss) {
             return false;
         })
     }
</script>
```

And here is my controller

```
    public function deletepost($id)
    {
         dd($id);
         DB::table('posters')->where('id', $id)->delete();
         return back()-> with('post_add', 'Post deleted Successfully');
    }
```

And my route

```
Route::delete ("/delete-post/{id}", [PosterController::class, "deletepost"])->name("poster.delete");
```

Comment: is deleting the data from database table: posters?

Comment: Yes it is deleting the data from posters table

Comment: Ok i think change this return back()-> with('post_add', 'Post deleted Successfully'); with return 'Post deleted successfully';

Comment: After that print this:  console.log(results)

Comment: It still didn't work

Comment: ok remove these two lines dd($id),dataType: 'JSON',  change this if (results.success === true) with if(results=='Post deleted successfully'). and provide me console.log(results) what it is printing if issue happens!

Comment: it deletes but shows error message and there is no error in my console

Comment: provide screenshot of your code!